# Scheduling threads in background at two different moments

Tags: android, cpu, background-process

In my application, I need to execute a method in 2 parts. 
The aim is to get the rate of a value between moment A and moment B.
Problem is that before moment B, the thread gets ignored if my application is in background. Indeed, Android CPU is not focusing on this thread anymore.
No matter what I tried, I still can not run it as I would like, any ideas will be much welcome.

I am using for this an ExecutorService that keeps my two Runnable threads (1st task, 2nd task) to be scheduled by a Timer. I have for sure added a Wake Lock parameter, and am also using a service to execute this as a background thread.

Android manifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
      ...
    <service
        android:name=".AnalysisService"
        android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
```

Analysis.java :

```
public static void runAnalysis(final Context context, final Analysis toRun){

    try{

        final Runnable firstTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                launchWakeLock(context);

                startAnalysis(context, toRun);

            }
        };

        final Runnable secondTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(isStillRunning(context,toRun)){

                    finishAnalysis(context, toRun);

                    getResult(context, toRun.getId());

                    showNotification(context, toRun);

                }

                stopWakeLock(context);

            }
        };

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

        Date dateStart = new Date();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, toRun.getDuration()*60);

        Date dateEnd = calendar.getTime();

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executorService.execute(firstTask);
            }
        }, dateStart);

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executorService.execute(secondTask);
            }
        }, dateEnd);

    }catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println(ex);

    }

}
```

Service.java :

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {

        final Analysis analysis = (Analysis) intent.getExtras().getSerializable(Analysis.extraIntentPath);

        if(analysis != null){

            Analysis.runAnalysis(getApplicationContext(), analysis);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to show a notification stating that your application is doing background work. This way the service would continue to run in the background.

Comment: Well I' d like to try, can you provide more explanations/sources please ?